# Create tabs for the QGIS plugin interface using Qt Creator

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3, qt, qt-designer

Is it possible to create **tabs** for QGIS plugin using **Qt Creator**? (Something like the image I attached)

I am trying to group the functionalities I developed for QGIS plugin and I think using multiple tabs will be a great idea.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can add the Tab Widget in Qt Creator.

[image]

Comment: oh snap i didn't know about this - awesome stuff.